# Impossible to remove remote desktop license server

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

The server that was the license server for my remote desktop server was decommissioned, so I want to remove it from the configuration.

If I go in `Server Manager > Remote Desktop Services > Overview` and then `RD Licensing > right click > Remove RD Licensing Servers` I end up with `Could not remove the configuration. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

If I try to do it with PowerShell using `remove-rdserver server.domain.local rds-licensing` I get the same error with more "details"

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStateFailed
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Is there a way to remove this old license server? Without deleting the whole remote desktop configuration and re-creating everything I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Login with the SQL-Manager Server to the localhost.

```
\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query

TSQL> To remove the orphaned Server with the ID 1005.
use RDCms
delete from rds.RoleRdsh where ServerId = ‘1005’
```

---

Dave Harris wrote a excelent blog to this issue.

https://dave.harris.uno/unable-to-remove-deleted-session-hosts-from-rds2012-deployment/